# Are there any remote sites available to apply shellshock on?

Tags: shellshock

I'm a grad student. We're looking for a remote site to perform shellshock for educational purposes. Sites which are willingly vulnerable for ethical hacking purposes??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were a few sites but they are no longer online. Your best bet is to grab a VM and perform the test locally. There's a good VM and Walkthrough available from PentesterLab - https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/cve-2014-6271

Comment: Yes I guess so. Would have preffered a live site.

Comment: A VM is indeed a 'live site' that belongs to you.  If you think it would make a demonstration more meaningful to your audience, you could run the VM on AWS or other cloud provider; but I promise you that audiences won't care.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/CompSec/labs.html

There are a whole set of free labs (including shellshock), an unpatched Ubuntu image, and even instructions on how to set up VirtualBox to run the VM on your own machine if you are unfamiliar.

An excellent resource that we use for our classes. Have fun!